# What is this bulb-on-a-stick moss?

Tags: identification

After winter I just started watering my potted plants again, and the moss seems to have come back to life as well. This time there are these unusual bulby things on stems. What are they?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the wonderful world of moss and lichen - these are likely gametophytes, possibly sporophytes, which are both to do with the moss reproducing. As its name suggests, sporophytes contain spores which eventually get released when they're mature. I'm not sure which type of moss (or lichen, possibly) this is, but some general information here http://u.osu.edu/biomuseum/2015/11/09/what-does-it-mean-to-be-a-moss/

If you like the moss, fine, but it is an indication that the soil in the pot is not just damp, but compacted, which likely isn't great for whatever plant you have growing in with it.